# UK fiance visa... dependent child

Tags: visas

Should I add my child as a dependent child even if they are not travelling or joining me in the UK. I'm divorced for 11 years and my children live with their mother.

Comment: Is your child actually dependent on you? Do you provide for them, actually look after them? At least some of the time?

Comment: Do you mean a Marriage Visitor visa https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa or a Family visa https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse?

Comment: I pay maintenance for my children. I am applying for a fiancee visa. If successful we will be married in the Summer.The questions are confusing as the next question is

Comment: Are any other children travelling with you? But no children are travelling. And no I don't look after them. They are in Turkey with their mother and I live in Cyprus.

Comment: Assuming you are applying to marry and settle (not visit) in the UK, the Family visa requires you to give details of all children, even if they’re not applying. https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/provide-information